# Javascript error in IE / iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, iframe

have a problem with shopping cart JS ( add to cart ) - it does work normally as expected in Chrome, FF, Sarafi but doens't work in IE 11 and earlier ( suprisingle works in IE 8 )

JS file-https://volleyballcoachemag.com/jscripts/product.js

add to shopping cart / add to wishlist do not work in IE.

Probably the issue with window.location in IE,

version with iframe ( not working in IE ):

http://softballcoachemag.com/iframe-test/index.html

version that works in IE ( without iframe )
https://volleyballcoachemag.com/s-1-frame_tharrett.aspx

Solution needed so it will work within iframe

Comment: if you open the console in Chrome, you will see 11 errors. One of them:Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined s-1-frame_tharrett.aspx:46. IE don't skip errors, as Chrome, FF, Sarafi

Answer (score 0):

> 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined s-1-frame_tharrett.aspx:46'

Looking through your page source I couldn't find a reference to jquery, are you sure you linked it properly?
You have these two in the page you linked:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Services_files/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Services_files/jquery-migrate.js"></script>
```

However the server cannot find the linked file for me. JQuery defines '$', so I would reccomend ensuring it is linked correctly to run your JQuery script.

Comment: Just fix that issue but that doesn't help. Only problem i need to fix "add to cart" button not working on IE9, IE10, IE11 when page is under iframe but woks normally.